# PHP/MySQL - Best way to work with dates in DD MMM YYYY format?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I need to display dates in the **DD MMM YYYY** format on the website I'm working on. My first thought was to store the dates in a DATE type in MySQL, then convert to the proper format using PHP. However, this is just returning **01 Jan 1970** - not the actual date of **04 May 1891**.

I found a few other places where people have asked similar questions and the answer was always something like `SELECT date_format(dt, '%d/%m/%Y')` which was giving me **04/05/1891**. I want the month to be 3 characters (May, Jun, Jul, Aug, etc).

I thought about storing the dates as a VARCHAR but that seems like it would be bad practice. It looks like I will have to store the date as a string and will not be able to use the PHP date() function because it cannot handle dates prior to 1970.

I may want to do things like calculate ages which sounds painful when dealing with strings... I am wondering if anyone has a more elegant solution?

Comment: The PHP date function doesn't have problems with dates prior to 1970. You probably did something wrong parsing the date. Unless you are using PHP 5.1.0 or earlier, which hopefully is not the case, you should be able to use it.

Comment: Use `YYYY-MM-DD` format when storing dates to MySQL, and for retrieving dates.... convert between formats before insertion (if you don't use the correct format, you will get 01-Jan-1970 as your date) or before display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **DATE** to save your dates in your db.

DATE can store values from *'1000-01-01*' to *'9999-12-31'* ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html))

PHP's old date functions  (i.e. date(), strtotime()) are on 32 bits and therefore work only with UNIX timestamps (they're limited to the 1970-2038 range).

With PHP 5's new class [DateTime](https://www.php.net/DateTime) you can do for example:

```
$date = new DateTime("1780-06-01");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**EDIT**:
To compute the difference between two dates (as stated in your question), an easy way is:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%Y years');
```

Comment: The point here is that MySQL accepts only YYYY-MM-DD format, so that's how you should insert it. When you select it out, you can format it however you'd like.

Comment: +1 This is a great discovery about php new DateTime() capability!

Comment: I did not know about DateTime. Thank you for enlightening me and showing me how to use it. This has solved my problem. I was using date() and strtotime() which would explain why I was getting stuck in the 70s :(

Comment: And for my usage, I needed DD MMM YYYY so I changed the format (from your example) to `format('d M Y')`. Also, the `echo $d->` bit should have been `echo $date->` to stay consistent with the first line of code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a constants file....

```
define('OUTDATE','%d %b %Y');
define('INDATE', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Then (as noted in the comments), manipulate the strings using the constants.

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(birthday, ".OUTDATE.") FROM table1";
```